# Event handling assigned in a loop works against my expectations

Tags: javascript, for-loop, onclick, radio-button, event-listener

```js
const radio = document.getElementsByName('subject');

for (let i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
    radio[i].onclick = () => {
        alert(`You chose ${radio[i].value}.`);
    };
}
```

```html
<form name="testForm">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Subject List</legend>
      <p>Choose your favorite subject.</p>
      <label><input type="radio" name="subject" value="speaking">Speaking</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="subject" value="grammar">Grammar</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="subject" value="writing">Writing</label>       
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

for-loop runs only once when the document is loaded, but I don't know why the alert pops up every time I click the input.

Shouldn't "radio.onclick" be outside to act as a trigger?

Comment: It works because it is how to assign an event handler to multiple elements. I would personally use delegation.  [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Comment: The loop simply adds an `onclick` function to each radio `input`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is about why something works the way it does, when it works the way it does

Comment: If you have a `<button>` and assign it a click handler, would you expect that handler to run just once?  Or every time you click the button?

Comment: I wanted to execute every time I click the button. But before I tried click the button, I thought it wouldn't run because `.onclick` is inside. But now I know how it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for-loop runs only once when the document is loaded, but I don't know why the alert pops up every time I click the input.

The loop goes to each radio button in turn. Inside the loop you say "When this radio button is clicked, run this function".

You click a radio button, the function runs. You click it again, the function runs again.

You never tell it to *stop* doing things when you click a radio button so there's no reason for it *not* to run the function every time you click an input.

> Shouldn't "radio.onclick" be outside to act as a trigger?

Then you would be trying to say "When this Node List is clicked, call this function."

There are two problems with that.

1. Node Lists are somewhat abstract. They aren't things you can click on. So assigning an `onclick` property does nothing.
2. Since you are proposing putting the loop inside the function you assign to `onclick` then, **if point 1 was not true**, a **single** click on *any* radio button (i.e. anywhere on the Node List) would trigger the loop and make **three** alerts (one for each radio button)

---

Asides:

- `onclick` assignments have some drawbacks (you can't assign multiple event listeners, assigning one to the wrong kind of object generally fails silently instead of producing an error). It is recommended to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.
- The approach for binding a single event listener which handles multiple similar UI controls is called [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
It is correct that it is intended to be executed every click.
But, when I checked with `console.log`, it seems that for-loop only runs once, so I was wondering why it works normally.
I was missing the basics.